# Terraform data block keeps saying the resources were not found

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm trying to get some resource ID's from resources that were deployed by another terraform pipeline, by using a data block. For example, subnet ID's for usage in a storage account block in azure.
But, I'm getting the same kind of error on all 4 data blocks that I'm trying:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "data_subnet" {
  name = "DataSubnet"
  virtual_network_name = "vnet-${var.lztri}-${var.env}-${var.loc}${var.stage != "" ? "-" : ""}${var.stage}-01"
  resource_group_name = "rg-${var.lztri}-network-${var.env}${var.stage != "" ? "-" : ""}${var.stage}-${var.loc}"
}
```

```
 Error: Subnet: (Name "DataSubnet" / Virtual Network Name "vnet-phr-dev-weu-01" / Resource Group "rg-phr-network-dev-weu") was not found
 
   with data.azurerm_subnet.data_subnet,
   on main.tf line 12, in data "azurerm_subnet" "data_subnet":
   12: data "azurerm_subnet" "data_subnet" {
```

But if I look for the 'not found' resources, I'm able to find them in the portal.

Comment: did you run terraform locally? try to find that resource via "az cli", this can be an issue with access rights

Comment: No, using Azure DevOps, but will try locally.

Answer (score 2):

Got this issue solved, in the azure devops console I got the errors, saying the resources were not found, but I executed that piece of code locally on my laptop, got the same error, but with an piece of extra info; it showed the subscriptionID where it was trying to find the resources. And this was wrong, this was the subscription of the SPN, not of the deployment. So I had to specify the subscription ID in the provider and it worked!